# Lower bound for the number of coin weightings

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

The book that I am currently studying has the following exercise.

Given is a set of $n$ coins of weights $0$ or $1$ and a scale to weight them. We would like to determine the weight of each coin by using the smallest amount of weightings possible.

I am asked to show using the pigeonhole principle that we need at least $n/\log_2{(n+1)}$ weightings.

The hint suggested that I define a determing sequence $S_1,\ldots,S_m$ to be a collections of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that for any subset $T \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ the sequence $|T\cap S_1|,\ldots,|T \cap S_m|$ uniquely determines $T$ and deduce the claim from the fact that $|T \cap S_i|$ can have at most $n+1$ values.

Somehow I don't see how to go from here. How can I obtain the desired result from this point?

Comment: What kind of scale do you have? A balance that gives you the sign of the total difference between coins on the left pan and coins on the right pan? Or one that gives you the sum weight as a number (i.e. you can query $\sum_{i\in I} w_i$ for any subset $I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$? From the hint I assume the latter ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes the later is the case. You are given a scale that can give you the weight of any subset of the coins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $T$ be the (unknown) set of heavy coins.
Any weighing strategy must look as follows:
At the $k$th step, you select a subset $S_k\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ (where the choice of $S_k$ may depend on the weighing results of previous rounds, but that does not matter) and the scale tells you the $k$th weighing result $w_k=|T\cap S_k|$, which is a number between $0$ and $|S_k|\le n$, inclusive. After a sequence of $m$ weighings, all you have is this sequence $w_1, \ldots, w_m$ (at most $(n+1)^m$ possibilities) and this must allow you to determine any of the candidates for $T$ (for which there are $2^n$ possibilities).
Therefore we must have $(n+1)^m\ge 2^n$, i.e. $m\log_2(n+1)\ge n$.